# Filter by related model's field in Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have simple mailData Model and mail Model

this is relationship in mailData:

```
function mail(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Mail::class);
}
```

here's my query:

```
$m = MailData::where('user_id', $userId)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
```

but I want to filter by field 'favorite' which is in Mail Model. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan to filter and get data only by those, you can use

```
$m = MailData::with('mail')->whereHas('mail', function ($q) use ($value) {
        $q->where('favorite', $value);
    })
        ->where('user_id', $userId)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: and can I pass 'your_value' in this function?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
    $m = MailData::with('mail')->whereHas('mail',function($q) use($v){
           //filter the field favorite here..
           //example
           $q->where('favorite','like',$v);
         })->where('user_id', $userId)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: and can I pass 'something' value in this function?

Comment: `$v`  is your filter value. Answer editted. @zbyshekh